# How do I properly disable cgi scripts e.g. guestbook.cgi on WHM

Tags: cgi, pci-dss

After a PCI scan identified guestbook.cgi as a risk, I want to disable the cgi-scripts installed by WHM (v11, running on CentOS5). I would like to do this "properly" using the WHM Web interface if possible (so this configuration survives an update and is easily reproduced).

Things I've tried so far that aren't satisfactory:

1. `chmod 0 /usr/local/cpanel/base/cgi-sys/guestbook.cgi`

   `chattr +i /usr/local/cpanel/base/cgi/guestbook.cgi`

   = throws a 500 Internal Server Error when visiting example.com/cgi-sys/guestbook.cgi and may interfere with automatic updates
2. WHM | Packages | Feature Manager | Edit a Feature List

   Disabled CGI Center

   Disabled Email Scripts (cgiemail,formmail)

   Disabled Simple Guestbook

   Disabled Advanced Guestbook

   = no change when visiting example.com/cgi-sys/guestbook.cgi (HTTP200 No Username given)

I've search forums.cpanel.net, which are usually pretty good but I can't find an answer that doesn't have undesirable side effects.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @HopelessN00b This should be re-opened and that "topics" list should be updated. Cpanel in itself is not a service provider. And the OP is working at WHM level, not cPanel account level...therefore he most likely *is* the service provider. Also, solving this question can't even be done via WHM/cPanel, only SSH/console. Settings changed in WHM don't actually do anything besides limit cPanel accounts from using it. Finally this guestbook.cgi (along with the other legacy cgi in that dir) is also a huge deal because it causes PCI failures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using WHM's 'Include Editor' (for httpd.conf edits that survive an update) but settled on using a .htaccess file in `/usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/` instead. I'm sure there's a probably a better way to do it but this works for me:

```
# cat /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^guestbook.cgi$ [G,L]

# chattr +i /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/.htaccess
```

Comment: if there's a _proper_ way to do it I'd like to hear suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2):

To disable cPanel's "CGI Center" scripts via WHM for all accounts or a specific plan:

1. After logging into WHM navigate to **Packages** > **Feature Manager**
2. Select the feature list your plans are using under **Edit a Feature List** (to check edit the plan under **Packages** > **Edit a Package**)
3. Uncheck **CGI Center**, click **Save**

To disable for a specific account (per cPanel), see https://forums.cpanel.net/f5/one-more-immutable-files-preventing-cpanel-whm-updating-your-serve-214301-p2.html#post1017292